# Ratpack: serving static resources from classpath

Tags: java, groovy, ratpack

My app has a dependency on another project containing a React SPA. When the app builds, all static resources are copied into build dir / jar with the following structure:

```
../
 |- index.html
 |- webroot
    |- static
    |   |- static/css/2.f5b2e8f7.chunk.css
    |   |- static/js/2.50b282b9.chunk.js
    |
    |- favicon.ico
```

and therefore available via classpath.

Now, when I render the `index.html` like so:

```
handlers {     
    get{
      response.contentType 'text/html'
      render getClass().getResource( '/index.html' ).text
    }
}
```

I see the following errors in the logs:

> .. ERROR r.e.i.DefaultDevelopmentErrorHandler - 404 client error for request to /static/favicon.ico
>
> .. ERROR r.e.i.DefaultDevelopmentErrorHandler - 404 client error for request to /static/static/css/2.f5b2e8f7.chunk.css

How can I make all those `/webroot/static/**` -> `/static/static/**` files accessible?

I tried looking at `ratpack-asset-pipeline` to accomplish what I need, but failed to find anything classpath-related.

In a sister app based on `Micronaut` I defined the following piece of config to enable static resources:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8890
    cors.enabled: true
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true   
        mapping: /static/**  
        paths: 
          - "classpath:webroot"
```

What is Ratpack's counterpart for this?

Comment: Would it not work if you create a handler get('static') that serves the webroot files?

Comment: @JacobAaeMikkelsen I was looking for out-of-box solution

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks like the following [issue](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/issues/1642) related to exposing external ressources (e.g. upload directory) if you agree?